# check if all values in a dict satisfy a specific condition

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a large dictionary object and i want to iterate through all the values and check if all the values do not satisfy a specific condition.
i want to use something like for-all or for-each.
in python it could be done as follows:

```
all(value == 0 for value in your_dict.values())
```

I want to know the equivalent to it in angular/typescript please

Comment: Are you using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)? [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` with `every()`, as in

```js
const nums = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}
const areAllEven = Object.values(nums).every(num => num % 2 === 0);
console.log(areAllEven);
```

Objects are more common, but Maps are a better replacement for a dict. If you used that instead, you would write `nums.values().every(...`